# How to specify that 0 is not a null cell in Excel?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a new rule in my Excel sheet where if a cell is equal to 0, then the cell is filled with a specefic color.

When I apply this rule, all the empty cells take on that color as well as the cells with the value 0.

I've been looking for an option in Excel to tell it that null cells != the value 0 but I can't find anything (I know that by default 0 = null).

My rule is "if cell value is" + "equal to" + "=0"

Thanks for helping me :)

Quick edit:
Here's a screenshot of the tool I'm using to create the rule :
[image]

Comment: You're probably looking for the function `isblank`.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark can I use that function in the tool I'm showing in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create rule with type 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format', add formula

`=(A1=0)*(A1<>"")`

(replace `A1` with first cell's address of `Applies to` range), select desired range into `Applies to` field.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would need to determine the formatting by a formula (the last item in the dialog of which you posted a picture) and then use this formula (or its French equivalent).

```
=AND(VALUE(A1)=0,ISBLANK(A1)=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You colud first transform all your empty cells in empty string and then apply the format colour if it is equal to zero.

You can transform the empty cells with this formula:

```
=IF(A1="","",A1)
```